# Selenium: source code for the different locator types?

Tags: selenium, c#

So, I've been wanting to take a look at the dotNet code for the different locator strategies (Id, ClassName, XPath, TagName, ...).

In the [By class](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/By.cs), I've found this for `Id`:

```
by.findElementMethod = (ISearchContext context) => ((IFindsById)context).FindElementById(idToFind);
by.findElementsMethod = (ISearchContext context) => ((IFindsById)context).FindElementsById(idToFind);
```

The [interface is here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/dotnet/src/webdriver/Internal/IFindsById.cs), but that's only the method signature of course.
Searching the project doesn't yield any other results.

Where is the actual implementation?

Comment: Is RemoteDriver what you're looking for?  It looks like all the strategies/mechanisms go through the [FindElement](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs#L1096-L1103) method and ultimately [sent to the server](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.cs#L93-L136).

Comment: Hmm... so the actual code to locate an element (e.g. by PartialLinkText) is defined in the specific browser drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the [different C# browser drivers](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/src/webdriver) all extend [RemoteDriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/RemoteWebDriver.cs) and end up [sending the find elements commands over HTTP](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/dotnet/src/webdriver/Remote/HttpCommandExecutor.cs#L93-L136) using the [WebDriver](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html) protocol.  Therefore, the actual finding of elements within the DOM does not take place in the C# driver code.  Instead, it's ultimately up to the browsers themselves to provide responses to these commands.  For example, in Chromium/Chrome, the implementation of these commands seems to be [stored as minified JavaScript within a C++ file (?!)](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/webdriver/atoms.cc#1216), and the [generation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/webdriver/README.chromium) of that code is based on [JavaScript files](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/c10e8a955883f004452cdde18096d70738397788/javascript/atoms/locators) from the Selenium codebase.

Comment: Nice, those Javascript files seem to be what I was looking for.